In SwiftUI Automatically updating views for Sonoma & newer ColorScheme appearance ( .dark, .light. system )
Fixed - Issue with any 'beta' XCode 16; XCode 15.4 works fine.
I did read several other topics about this, but none did solve this, the updating of the document window + views.
I create a swiftui application with several windows, setting view and documents window.
With the current code everything was is opened after the appearance change is showing the correct appearance .light/.dark/ system. But the already opened document window are not updated. F.e the settings window is updated during a change of appearance; why not the others?
The MyApp.swift file
    import SwiftUI

@main
struct darkSpiritApp: App {
    @AppStorage("appearanceSelection") private var appearanceSelection: Int = 0
 //   @AppStorage("appearanceMode") private var appearanceModeRawValue: String = AppearanceMode.system.rawValue
    
    
    var appearanceSwitch: ColorScheme? { // '?' for accepting the nil/none as 'system wide' setting.
        if appearanceSelection == 1 {
            return .light
        }
        else if appearanceSelection == 2 {
            return .dark
        }
        else {
            return .none
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
           //    .environment(\.colorScheme, AppearanceMode(rawValue: appearanceModeRawValue)?.colorScheme ?? .none ) // give error
               .preferredColorScheme(appearanceSwitch)
        }
        
        Settings {
            PreferencesView()
              .preferredColorScheme(appearanceSwitch)
        }
    }
    
}


//enum AppearanceMode: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
//    case system = "System"
//    case light = "Light"
//    case dark = "Dark"
//
//    var id: String { rawValue }
//    
//    var colorScheme: ColorScheme? {
//        switch self {
//        case .system:
//            return nil
//        case .light:
//            return .light
//        case .dark:
//            return .dark
//        }
//    }
//}

===
The ContentView and prefferencesView AppaeranceView file
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct PreferencesView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = "General"
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("General settings")
                    .padding()
                
                AppearanceSelectionView()
                    .padding()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("General")
            }
            .tag("General")
            
            
            Text("Nothing else dark matter")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Extensions")
                }
                .tag("Extensions")
            
            Text("Version settings go here")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Version Settings")
                }
                .tag("Version Settings")
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 300)
    }
}

struct AppearanceSelectionView: View {
    @AppStorage("appearanceSelection") private var appearanceSelection: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Picker(selection: $appearanceSelection) {
                Text("System")
                    .tag(0)
                Text("Light")
                    .tag(1)
                Text("Dark")
                    .tag(2)
            } label: {
              Text("Select Appearance")
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
    }
}

As you can see I did try to use ( have it commented out to let it compile ).
environment(\.colorScheme, AppearanceMode(rawValue: appearanceModeRawValue)?.colorScheme ?? .none )

How can I force an update? Being trying the provided sample doesn't work. I use Sonoma with XCode16.1, but the older XCode version gives the same result.

Your code works on machine, macOS 14.5.

Thank you for your reply. To be clear for me - You mean the existing already open document window changes automaticaly when you changes the appearance setting in the prefferences window?

You have no DocumentGroups, so I assume "document window" refers to ContentView? Yes that changes appearance automatically.

Yes you are right, in the original app I do use a DocumentsGroup; but in the sample app not, but in both tests it doens't work well apparently. Also when set it to system al the text go white instead of black. Weird, very weird. Side Note I use 14.6.1 now.

I figure it out. It was XCode 16 and the Project format 16.  XCode 15.4 and any XCode format works fine.
